# How to embed youtube video in firefox os webapp?

Tags: angularjs, firefox-os

I am getting the cross origin error in console log. is there any way we can embed like ?Any Firefox OS CSP settings for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Firefox

```
var activity = new MozActivity({
name: "view",
data: {
type: [
  "video/webm",
  "video/mp4",
  "video/3gpp",
  "video/youtube"
],
url: "http://example.com/myvideo.mp4"
}
 });
```